# Flickering of background image when it is set with data binding

Tags: android, xml, data-binding, android-glide

I am setting the background of fragment with data binding in android. Since the background can change dynamically i am setting it in xml like this:

```
app:image="@{variable.getBackgroundImage()}"
```

The getBackgroundImage() will give the path of the background.
I am using glide to set the background like this:

```
Glide.with(view.getContext()).load(url + File.separator + path)
                    .dontAnimate()
                    .into(new SimpleTarget<GlideDrawable>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, GlideAnimation<? super GlideDrawable> glideAnimation) {
                            view.setBackground(resource);
                        }
                    });
```

The image is getting set but there is a momentary flickering of the pre-set background in the xml.

How can i avoid this flicker of the background?

Comment: I can only think of two things: either Glide takes a moment to load the resource or you are not running `executePendingBindings()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue.The issue was with glide. I am now setting the background without glide and its working fine.No flicker.

```
BitmapDrawable bd = new BitmapDrawable(view.getContext().getResources(), BitmapFactory.decodeFile(url + File.separator + path));
            view.setBackground(bd);
```